# How to add a URL to download a file in java

Tags: java, url, zip

I want to add a URL into my java program: http://www.markit.com/news/InterestRates_JPY_20160426.zip; so basically when you open this link a zip file is downloaded. How do I do that?

And then, I want to unzip the downloaded file in the java program as well.

How do I do these in java?

Comment: We will help you, but we will not write your code.

Comment: @gonz Is it possible to use curl in windows java?

Comment: @user3591433 I don't know, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) to unzip your file.

To download a file in Java you can use this code.

```
try
{
    String url = "download url";
    String path = "C:/Users/...."; // Path to where the files is going to be downloaded.
    ReadableByteChannel in = Channels.newChannel( new URL(url).openStream() );
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
    FileChannel out = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
    out.transferFrom(in, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at the ReableByteChannel line